# Сортировка таблицы, по нажатию на заголовок столбца

Tags: php, javascript, html

Здравствуйте.
Сделал сортировку столбцов таблицы по клику на соответствующий заголовок, а теперь хочу для вида добавить еще и тип сортировки, т.е чтобы отображалась картинка со стрелочкой, показывающая тип сортировки...Как эту стрелочку влепить сюда и чтобы она появлялась и изменялась только в том столбце, по которому производится сортировка?

```
 <?php 
    $key_array = array('id','date','surname','name','patronymic', 'text');
    $sort_array = array('asc','desc');

    if (isset($_GET['key']))
    {
     $key=$_GET['key'];
     $sort=$_GET['sort'];
   }
   else
   {
     $key='id';
     $sort='asc';
   }

   if(in_array($key, $key_array) && in_array($sort, $sort_array))
   {
     $query = "SELECT id,DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%d.%m.%Y') as `date`,surname,name,patronymic,text FROM message ORDER BY $key $sort";
     $result = mysql_query($query);
   }
   else exit("неверный формат запроса!");   

   if($sort=='asc')
   {
     $sort='desc';
   }
   else
   {
     $sort='asc';

   }

   print "<table class='table table_sort'>";
   print "<thead>";
   print "<tr>
   <th class='col-md-1 tbl_tlt'><a href=\"index.php?key=id&sort=$sort\">ID</a></th>
   <th class='col-md-2 tbl_tlt'><a href=\"index.php?key=date&sort=$sort\">Дата рождения</a></th>
   <th class='col-md-2 tbl_tlt'><a href=\"index.php?key=surname&sort=$sort\">Фамилия</a></th>
   <th class='col-md-2 tbl_tlt'><a href=\"index.php?key=name&sort=$sort\">Имя</a></th>
   <th class='col-md-2 tbl_tlt'><a href=\"index.php?key=patronymic&sort=$sort\">Отчество</a>
   <th class='col-md-2 tbl_tlt'><a href=\"index.php?key=text&sort=$sort\">Биография</a>
   </th></tr>";
   print "</thead>";
   print "<tbody>";
// Отформатировать и вывести каждую строку таблицы
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {

     print "<tr>";
     print '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td><td>'.$row['date'].'</td><td>'.$row['surname'].'</td><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td>'.$row['patronymic'].'</td><td>'.$row['text'].'</td>';
     print "</tr>";
   }
   print "<tbody>";
// Завершить таблицу
   print "</table>";
   ?>
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, Вам должно подойти http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: Нужно сделать без плагинов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заведите массив, в котором будут сложены параметры, по которым выводятся заголовки:

```
$theads = array(
    'id' => array('name' => 'ID', 'cols' => '1'),
    'date' => array('name' => 'Дата рождения', 'cols' => '2'),
    'surname' => array('name' => 'Фамилия', 'cols' => '2'),
    'name' => array('name' => 'Имя', 'cols' => '2'),
    'patronymic' => array('name' => 'Отчество', 'cols' => '2'),
    'text' => array('name' => 'Биография', 'cols' => '2'),
);
```

Затем вместо 6 print-ов сделайте в цикле один. Весь пример:

```
$key_array = array('id', 'date', 'surname', 'name', 'patronymic', 'text');
$sort_array = array('asc', 'desc');

$theads = array(
    'id' => array('name' => 'ID', 'cols' => '1'),
    'date' => array('name' => 'Дата рождения', 'cols' => '2'),
    'surname' => array('name' => 'Фамилия', 'cols' => '2'),
    'name' => array('name' => 'Имя', 'cols' => '2'),
    'patronymic' => array('name' => 'Отчество', 'cols' => '2'),
    'text' => array('name' => 'Биография', 'cols' => '2'),
);

if (isset($_GET['key'])) {
    $key = $_GET['key'];
    $sort = $_GET['sort'];
} else {
    $key = 'id';
    $sort = 'asc';
}

if(in_array($key, $key_array) && in_array($sort, $sort_array))
{
    $query = "SELECT id,DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%d.%m.%Y') as `date`,surname,name,patronymic,text FROM message ORDER BY $key $sort";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
}
else exit("неверный формат запроса!");

print "<table class='table table_sort'>";
print "<thead>";
foreach ($theads as $k => $thead) {
    if ($k === $key) {
        $img = "/put/do/kartinki/$sort.jpg";
        $soort = ($sort == 'desc' ? 'asc' : 'desc');
    } else {
        $img = '';
        $soort = 'asc';
    }
    $get = http_build_query(array(
        'key' => $k,
        'sort' => $soort
    ));
    print "<th class='col-md-{$thead['cols']} tbl_tlt'>$img<a href=\"?$get\">{$thead['name']}</a></th>";
}
print "</thead>";
print "<tbody>";
// Отформатировать и вывести каждую строку таблицы
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    print "<tr>";
    print '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td><td>'.$row['date'].'</td><td>'.$row['surname'].'</td><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td>'.$row['patronymic'].'</td><td>'.$row['text'].'</td>';
    print "</tr>";
}
print "<tbody>";
// Завершить таблицу
print "</table>";
```

Comment: Спасибо, но немного не понимаю за место каких принтов именно

Comment: @Artemfomkin, поменял немного, так понятнее должно быть. Вот от Вашего кода `print "<thead>";` и до `print "</thead>";` включительно, этот кусок меняете на тот, что у меня во второй части.

Comment: Жалуется на этот код
 $theads = [
    'id' => ['name' => 'ID', 'cols' => '1'],
    'date' => ['name' => 'Дата рождения', 'cols' => '2'],
    'surname' => ['name' => 'Фамилия', 'cols' => '2'],
    'name' => ['name' => 'Имя', 'cols' => '2'],
    'patronymic' => ['name' => 'Отчество', 'cols' => '2'],
    'text' => ['name' => 'Биография', 'cols' => '2'],
];
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in Z:\home\Bootst3.ru\www\index.php on line 98

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.13

Comment: @Artemfomkin, конструкция `[...]` эквивалентна конструкции `array(...)`. Заменил в ответе.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, я делал тоже array, но лишь к $theads = array(

Comment: Стрелка появляется, но как сделать чтобы при еще нажатии они менялась

Comment: @Artemfomkin, добавил в ответ. Заодно рекомендую не собирать вручную строку запроса - мало ли что, проще это дело отдать на растерзание функции `http_build_query`. Сейчас не страшно, два параметра, а если их будет 10?) да еще и строковые с пробелами всякими жуткими и **кавычками**. Не экранировать же всё руками.

Comment: Вставил код, теперь если второй раз нажать на заголовок, он не сортирует его в порядке убывания. И вот еще вопрос а как будет меняться положение стрелки если только один $img

Comment: @Artemfomkin, не заметил, что Вы меняете параметр. Старайтесь для отдельных целей использовать отдельные переменные. Мы же не в 20 веке живем, памяти хватает. Ответ отредактировал и проверил - теперь точно должно работать.

Comment: Сортировка работает, только я не могу понять как изменить "asc" "desc"  на стрелки

Comment: @Artemfomkin, Вам нужно заменить в этой части: `if ($k === $key) {
        $img = "/put/do/kartinki/$sort.jpg";
        $soort = ($sort == 'desc' ? 'asc' : 'desc');
    }` Вам нужно заменить и указать путь до картинок со стрелочкой. Либо нужно назвать картинки соответствующе - asc.jpg и desc.jpg соответственно, либо там воткнуть функцию, которая будет возвращать путь до картинки, ну либо в явном виде через тернарный if сделать.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все работает